# Does a nominee of the US Republican party, to the US presidential elections, have to be a party member?

Tags: united-states, election, president

Search as I may, even in the US Republican Party (GOP) rule book, I cannot find a definitive answer to this question, maybe I am not reading it correctly:

For the US presidential elections, does a nominee of the US Republican Party (GOP) have to be a member of the Republican Party (GOP)?

Comment: I don't think the [rules have been](http://www.politico.com/story/2016/03/republican-campaign-rules-committee-trump-220590) determined yet. They don't set those until after June I think.

Comment: Maybe I should have said "candidates" as opposed to "nominees", as my question relates to whether people running for a party now have to be members. Namely thinking of D. T.

Comment: The answer is no then, you need not be a member of the GOP to run in the Republican Party Primary.

Comment: why don't you spell check 'ellections' first

Comment: @anon0909 - [edit link](http://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/10570/edit), is a more constructive way of handling misspellings

Comment: Related, but not quite a duplicate: http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10445/how-did-donald-trump-or-ben-carson-become-a-republican-candidate/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules for the nominee are set by the individual state. That is, each state determines under what circumstances it will allow a candidate for nomination to appear on the primary ballot. The state rules only deal with the filing requirements for getting on the ballot in the individual state.

While the rules do not explicitly require official membership or registration in the party, the petition signature requirements may do so. States may require that voters in a primary be registered for a specific party (as in Maryland), but some states have "open" primaries.

[Marylandprimary ballot](https://ballotpedia.org/Ballot_access_requirements_for_political_candidates_in_Maryland) for example does not seem to address the membership of the candidate in the party for which he is campaigning.

> **For principal party candidates**
>
> A candidate for federal, statewide or state legislative office seeking
>   the nomination of a principal political party in a primary election
>   must submit to the Maryland State Board of Elections a certificate of
>   candidacy, which notes the office being sought, the year of the
>   election, the name and address of the candidate, and includes a
>   statement verifying that the candidate satisfies the legal
>   requirements for candidacy for the office being sought. A candidate
>   for statewide or state legislative office must also submit a financial
>   disclosure form to the Maryland State Ethics Commission.[4][5]

Kansas also appears to have similar rules.

> **For party candidates**
>
> See statutes: Kansas Statutes, Chapter 25, Article 2,
>   Section 5
>
> A candidate seeking the nomination of a party qualified to participate
>   in primary elections can gain access to the primary ballot in one of
>   two ways. These are detailed below. By filing a nomination petition
>
> Signature requirements for nomination petitions for party candidates
>   vary according to the office being sought. For offices elected on a
>   statewide basis, signatures must equal at least 1 percent of the
>   state's current voter registration total of the party whose nomination
>   the candidate is seeking. Gubernatorial candidates must collect
>   signatures equaling at least 1 percent of the total votes cast for the
>   party's candidate for secretary of state at the last preceding
>   election. For offices elected by district, signatures must equal at
>   least 2 percent of the district's current voter registration total of
>   the party whose nomination the candidate is seeking.[2][3]
>
> Nomination petitions for federal and state-level offices (including
>   state legislative seats) must be submitted to the Kansas Secretary of
>   State by noon on June 1, prior to the primary election. If June 1
>   falls on a holiday or weekend, petitions are due by noon on the next
>   following business day.[2] By paying a filing fee
>
> A candidate may forgo the petition process by submitting a declaration
>   of candidacy and paying a filing fee. The filing fee varies according
>   to the office being sought. For statewide and federal offices, the fee
>   is equal to 1 percent of the office's annual salary. For state senate
>   candidates, the fee is $75. For state representative candidates, the
>   fee is $50.[2][4]
>
> The declaration and accompanying filing fee for federal and
>   state-level offices (including state legislative seats) must be
>   submitted to the Kansas Secretary of State by noon on June 1, prior to
>   the primary election. If June 1 falls on a holiday or weekend,
>   petitions are due by noon on the next following business day.[2]
>
> In addition to the statutory filing fee, a candidate for federal and
>   state offices must pay a $20 administrative fee to the Kansas
>   Secretary of State. A state-level candidate must also pay a
>   registration fee to the Kansas Governmental Ethics Commission. For
>   statewide executive offices, the fee is $480. For state legislative
>   candidates, the fee is $35.[5][6]