# Are there technical constraints in place that would prevent Harvey Weinstein from running for (and winning) US President?

Tags: united-states, president

Given America successfully had the current POTUS elected and sworn in, is there any reason that despite public outrage, someone like Harvey Weinstein couldn't become President?

Comment: A 'citation' demonstrating that Weinstein at some point in his career has suggested he might run for the presidency would 'tighten' your question; If you can't tell I'm joking...

Comment: Is it a joke question or are you being serious?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this counts as a duplicate or not: https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/10445/2130

Comment: I've voted to close this as off topic because you're asking us to speculate on the future, with an implied attack on the president.

Comment: @DrunkCynic  I do not want a speculative answer.  I'm asking what controls are in place the block the nomination of a notorious person (if any).  This is a legitimate concern to want to know if there is any lower limit to what is deemed acceptable.

Comment: @BigDataLouie I would recommend editing your question to remove the real-world elements and focus on your actual question then.  As it stands your question needlessly uses examples of real people, which tends to distract from the actual question.

Answer (score 2):

As long as one adheres to the [requirements per the constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_eligibility_legislation), they can run and become president:

> No person except a natural born Citizen, or a Citizen of the United States, at the time of the Adoption of this Constitution, shall be eligible to the Office of President; neither shall any person be eligible to that Office who shall not have attained to the Age of thirty five Years, and been fourteen Years a Resident within the United States.